# Custom DataGridView Cells

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, custom-controls

I need to create a custom control based on a datagrid. My need is to show the events of the day (I know there are other third-party controls).
I should redesign the cells in the datagridview but I do not know where to start, obviously do not want the code I understand that it is not a simple thing, but I would like to see one of your left indication on what to focus on.

Below is an image of what I would get
[image]

Comment: old school html tables and some fancy css could do that just fine

Comment: Html tables in vb.net O.o ?

Comment: @ScottSelby Looks like this is a vb.net question ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible with wiforms... It may be possible using WPF however.

Comment: this is not a great news !

Comment: Wow, can u tell me how ? What should I do? I do not know where to turn: | but I'm sure I will.